# JSON.parse to load JSON data into PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I wrote a JSON file like this

```
{
"q1":{
        "sn":"1.",
        "ques": "From the list of words lettered A to D choose the one that is <b>most nearly opposite in meaning</b> to the underlined word and that will, at the same time, correctly fill the gap in the sentence: The management has neither <u>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</u> nor <b><u>denied</u></b> the rumour that it was going to lay off some workers",
        "opt": "<br /><input type='radio' name='q1' /> pronounced <br /> <input type='radio' name='q1' /> confirmed <br /> <input type='radio' name='q1' /> rejected <br /> <input type='radio' name='q1' /> advertised"
    },

"q2":{
        "sn":"2.",
        "ques": "From the list of words lettered A to D choose the one that is <b>most nearly opposite in meaning</b> to the underlined word and that will, at the same time, correctly fill the gap in the sentence: The arrival of the police at the scene <u>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</u> rather than <b><u>mitigated</u></b> tension",
        "opt": "<br /><input type='radio' name='q2' /> provoked <br /> <input type='radio' name='q2' /> heightened <br /> <input type='radio' name='q2' /> created <br /> <input type='radio' name='q2' /> prolonged"
    },

"q3":{
        "sn":"3.",
        "ques": "From the list of words lettered A to D choose the interpretation that you consider <b>most appropriate</b> for this sentence: When I leave this country it will be for good. This means that i will",
        "opt": "<br /><input type='radio' name='q3' /> never come back <br /> <input type='radio' name='q3' /> leave for better conditions elsewhere <br /> <input type='radio' name='q3' /> become an adventurer <br /> <input type='radio' name='q3' /> improvement ways"
    },

"q4":{
        "sn":"4.",
        "ques": "From the list of words lettered A to D choose the word that <b>best completes</b> the following sentence: Because the new venture was <u>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</u> many businessman and women went into it.",
        "opt": "<br /><input type='radio' name='q4' /> rich <br /> <input type='radio' name='q4' /> manageable <br /> <input type='radio' name='q4' /> lucrative <br /> <input type='radio' name='q4' /> satisfying"
    },

"q5":{
        "sn":"5.",
        "ques": "From the list of words lettered A to D choose the one that is <b>nearly in meaning</b> to the underlined word and that will, at the same time, correctly fill the gap in the sentence: She was <b><u>reprimanded</u></b> by her boss for negligence",
        "opt": "<br /><input type='radio' name='q5' /> sacked <br /> <input type='radio' name='q5' /> rebuked <br /> <input type='radio' name='q5' /> punished <br /> <input type='radio' name='q5' /> surcharged"
    }
}
```

I want to create an online computer based exam.

I used JSON.parse to load the data in using PHP's `file_get_contents`(question.json);

My issue is that i want the data sets to load in one by one e.g q1 shows up first then when a next button is clicked q2 should show up until it gets to q5

i tried pushing it out into a javascript array like this using AJAX too

```
for(var obj in data) {
            //opt.arr.push(data[obj].opt);
            sn = data[obj].sn;
            ques = data[obj].ques;
            opt = data[obj].opt;
            //results.innerHTML += data[obj].sn+data[obj].ques+data[obj].opt+"<hr /><br />";
        }
        results.innerHTML += sn + ques + opt+"<hr /><br />";
```

i want to to create a computer based test like this
![Computer based test][1]

stackoverflow is not allowing me upload a picture when they do i'll upload how it should look like for better explanation.

When onload, the first set of questions e.g "q1": in the json file should be loaded out with its set of options and when the user clicks 2 or next the "q2": set of data in the json file should load out and hide the "q1": data set in the json file and if the user clicks 3 or next button below, only the data set "q3": in the json file should load out with its set of options and so on... if the next button is clicked, the next set of questions with its options should be loaded out.

I would also appreciate any idea on how to keep track of the answers selected by the user and check if it is correct.

Can someone put me through please. And i'm a bit new to JSON so ease it out a little bit.

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Errors? Unexpected results?

Comment: So I just wasted 10 minutes of my life typing up a full php solution, then he posts below he wants a javascript based solution. Don't waste your time.

Comment: Sorry!!! i really am. I will also need the php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I’m not entirely sure whether you are searching for a JavaScript- or php based solution, I will go with php. To turn a JSON array into a php array, you can use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) and then iterate through the array to do whatever you want with it (set variables, output the data, …

```
$questions= json_decode($your_json_file);

foreach($questions as $questionObj) {
    echo $questionObj['sn'];
    echo $questionObj['ques'];
    echo $questionObj['opt'];
}
```

Comment: I am searching for a javascript based solution